# android - Break line when string reaches display maximum display width on RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-xml

Im curently working on an app which has localization. One of the strings is fairly long, and when testing the app on both AVD and physical device, the text gets cut off when reaching the end of the screen.

[image: Screenshot taken from my phone]

**How do you break the text, making it go on a new line, when the text reaches the display maximum width?**

**Code:**

**item_settings.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/rvCard"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#121212"
        app:cardCornerRadius="90dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/rvIcon"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_colored_settings"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rvTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/rvDescription"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rvCard"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rvDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="@color/colorUnselected"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rvCard"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvTitle" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post item xml layout please.

Comment: @aminography updated the question, you cannnow check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `TextView` try this:

`android:singleLine="false"`

`android:maxLines="xxx"`  //replace xxx with the max number of lines you want to have dynamically.

And change your `TextView` width to `0dp` and do `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"`
your final code would look like

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rvDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textColor="@color/colorUnselected"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:maxLines="xxx"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rvTitle" />
```

Hope it helps!